# Switch between views by current user or group in Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I have infopath from with two forms.. So what i need to do is Switch those two views with current user group that logged into the system.. And im making this form to submit data into list not to a library..

In this case i can't use build in SharePoint Web Services to get those deatials about current user group..

So that is there any way to get current user group without using those web services.. Let's assume that i have two user groups `Builders and Viewers` and have two views `Builders View and Viewers View`

Comment: You might be able to use a SOAP Web Service data connection and the [UserGroup.GetGroupCollectionFromUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772552.aspx), but this problem has been so much of a pain for me that I ended up hard coding users into all my InfoPath forms.

Comment: Same problem here.. becasue we are doing production deployment.. we cant actually set web service path because exactly we cant say what is the site collection that we going to refer..